# How can I relate two tables in SQL that are related through a third one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, relational

My SQL skills have atrophied and I need some help connecting two tables through a third one that contains foreign keys to those two.

The Customer table has data I need. The Address table has data I need. They are not directly related to each other, but the CustomerAddress table has both CustomerID and AddressID columns.

Specifically, I need from the Customer table:

```
FirstName
MiddleName
LastName
```

...and from the Address table:

```
AddressLine1
AddressLine2
City
StateProvince, 
CountryRegion
PostalCode
```

Here is my awkward attempt, which syntax LINQPad does not even recognize ("*Incorrect syntax near '='*").

```
select C.FirstName, C.MiddleName, C.LastName, A.AddressLine1, A.AddressLine2, A.City, A.StateProvince, 
A.CountryRegion, A.PostalCode
from SalesLT.Customer C, SalesLT.Address A, SalesLT.CustomerAddress U
left join U.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
where A.AddressID = U.AddressID
```

Note: This is a SQL Server table, specifically AdventureWorksLT2012_Data.mdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select C.FirstName, C.MiddleName, C.LastName, A.AddressLine1, A.AddressLine2, A.City, A.StateProvince, 
A.CountryRegion, A.PostalCode
from  SalesLT.CustomerAddress U INNER JOIN SalesLT.Address A
ON A.AddressID = U.AddressID
INNER JOIN  SalesLT.Customer C
ON U.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
```

I have only used `INNER JOINS` but obviously you can replace them with `LEFT` or `RIGHT` joins depending on your requirements.

Comment: Think of it as building a chain. Start with one table that is the "master" and then start hooking on tables one at a time.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    c.FirstName,
    c.MiddleName,
    c.LastName,
    a.AddressLine1
    a.AddressLine2
    a.City
    a.StateProvince, 
    a.CountryRegion
    a.PostalCode
FROM Address a
JOIN CustomerAddress ca
    ON ca.AddressID = a.AddressID
JOIN Customer c
    ON c.CustomerID = ca.CustomerID
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The LEFT JOIN will include the customers that don't have an address.

```
    SELECT C.FirstName, C.MiddleName, C.LastName, A.AddressLine1, 
    A.AddressLine2, A.City, A.StateProvince, 
    A.CountryRegion, A.PostalCode
    FROM  Customer C
    LEFT JOIN CustomerAddress U 
    ON U.CustomerID = C.CustomerID  
    LEFT JOIN Address A
    ON A.AddressID = U.AddressID
    ORDER BY C.LastName, C.FirstName
```